# GridLayout columns disappearing on smaller screen devices

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm having some issues with my GridLayout contained within a ConstraintLayout. On larger screen devices (Pixel 2/3 XL for example) the GridLayout looks fine with content for all three columns showing up as expected.

On smaller screen devices only the first column is visible while the others just seem to disappear completely. What am I missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/login_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".myactivity.MyActivity">


  <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_gridlayout_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_layout"
        app:rowCount="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/md_keylines_medium"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activity_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_climate" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_state_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/activity_temp"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="22.0"
                app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_minus"
                app:chipIconSize="22dp"
                app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_add"
                app:closeIconEnabled="true"
                app:closeIconSize="22dp"
                app:closeIconTint="@color/colorAccent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/activity_toggle"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/start"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_power"
                app:chipIconTint="@color/colorWhite" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You should add Scrollview in this design. In this UI design, it will fit above 5.0 screen size but less than that it will get cut. @ardevd

Comment: Why will it be cut on smaller device screens? Is it not possible to have a gridview with three columns on screen sizes smaller than 5.0 inches?

Answer (score 1):

Just make `layout width 0dp where you are using column weight` and check:

Like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/login_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".myactivity.MyActivity">


  <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_gridlayout_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_layout"
        app:rowCount="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/md_keylines_medium"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activity_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_climate" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_state_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/activity_temp"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="22.0"
                app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_minus"
                app:chipIconSize="22dp"
                app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_add"
                app:closeIconEnabled="true"
                app:closeIconSize="22dp"
                app:closeIconTint="@color/colorAccent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/activity_toggle"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/start"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_power"
                app:chipIconTint="@color/colorWhite" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Design View should be like this

```
   <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{(v)->callback.onTabClick(v)}"
            app:touchListener="@{mContext}">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_card_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_menu_image"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_menu_image"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    app:imageResource="@{tabIcon}"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_guide_title"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"

                    tools:src="@drawable/guide_icon" />

                <!--android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"-->
                <com.hp.pregnancy.customviews.new_50.RobotoMediumTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_guide_title"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="@{tabTitle}"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/menu_color"
                    android:textFontWeight="500"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_card_icon"
                    tools:text="@string/guideTitle" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

For Grid Include like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include

        android:id="@+id/include2"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        layout="@layout/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        app:callback="@{callback}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tab3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include2"
       />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        layout="@layout/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tab4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include2"
       /> <!--guideLayout-->

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        layout="@layout/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tab5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab1"
        />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tab4"
        layout="@layout/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tab6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab2"
       />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tab5"
        layout="@layout/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab3"
      />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tab6"
        layout="@layout/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab4"
       />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you are testing for smaller screen add scrollview and constraintlayout in activity or fragment layout and then add include.

Comment: Not quite sure why this would work when mine doesnt? What specifically is the issue and what's the solution?

Comment: @ardevd There is nothing like that it totally depends on screen densities and size. What I provided a single design view and call include multiple time to avoid confusion among nested views.

Comment: @ardevd ScrollView is only option to handle all grid from small to large device. Just ignore binding methods.